# Convert program from QBasic to Python

Tags: python, qbasic

Im trying to convert a program that I made in Basic! (QBASIC on iOS) to Python. I am slowly working my way through Python for Dummies but I am stuck on how to convert FOR loops. Can someone help? Bellow is the QB code.

```
REM Prime Numbers v2

REM Av 2.2 seconds for 1000
REM Av 5.3 seconds for 2000

INPUT "Prime numbers upto";limit
PRINT
t1 = TickCount
PRINT "2 3 ";
count = 2
FOR posprime = 3 TO limit STEP 2
    posfactor = 3
    prime = 1
    GOSUB testing
    IF prime = 1 THEN
        PRINT posprime " ";
        count = count + 1
    END IF
NEXT posprime
t2 = TickCount
PRINT
PRINT
PRINT count " prime numbers found"
PRINT USING "####.#"; "Completed in" t2 - t1 " seconds"
END

testing:
IF posprime/posfactor = INT(posprime/posfactor) THEN
    prime = 0
    RETURN
ELSE
    posfactor = posfactor + 2
    IF posfactor > SQR(posprime) THEN
        RETURN
    ELSE
        GOTO testing
```

It is a program that me and my son made on Basic! (QBasic for iOS) that displays all the prime numbers up to the limit entered by the user with some added parts that skip obvious non-prime numbers. Oh and it includes a little speed check that we used to see the difference between iPhone and iPad processors.

Answer (score 4):

```
FOR posprime = 3 TO limit STEP 2
```

Above line could be translated into following Python code (limit exclusive):

```
for posprime in range(3, limit, 2):
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: It needs to go to limit+1: range(3, limit+1, 2)

Comment: Thank you for the responses. So range upper limit is up to but not including, hence needing limit+1?